# Switch Application.Mainform at runtime and invoke MainformOnTaskBar cause flickering on Windows Taskbar

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 2010 to build a Win32 GUI application running on Windows XP/Vista and Windows 7.

Basically, the Application.MainForm is a read only property and can't be changed at runtime once the first form is created via Application.CreateForm:

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

The above example will make Form1 as application's mainform.  It will show on Windows 7 taskbar's thumbnail preview.

Setting Application.MainFormOnTaskBar to true at runtime allow us to enjoy Windows aero theme features.

I need to switch the application's mainform at runtime.  For example, set Form2 as main form.  I use following code to make it work:

```
procedure SetAsMainForm(aForm:TForm);
var
  P:Pointer;
begin
  Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := False;
  try
    P := @Application.Mainform;
    Pointer(P^) := aForm;
    aForm.Show;
  finally
    Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetAsMainForm(Form2);
end;
```

Execute Button1.Click will make Form2 as mainform and update the Windows' taskbar thumbnail preview.  However, the Taskbar may flicker on the switching.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to away such flickering?
2. Is it safe to set Application.MainformOnTaskBar := False and set it to True again in runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main form isn't something you're allowed to change in Delphi. You managed to find a way that appears to work half-way, but it's a hack. Stop doing that.

An application has only one main form, and it's the first form that finishes being created via `CreateForm`. If you need two radically different behaviors for the main form, then you can try a couple of techniques:

- Define your two main forms as *frames*. Put all your functionality there. Then define a single form that will act as the parent of one of the two frames. Instead of switching the main form, simply destroy the frame and replace it with a new one.
- Similar to the frame solution, but use forms instead. Create the forms, and set the `Parent` property to be the "real" main form. This will probably have a lower initial cost because you already have the two forms, but in my experience, re-parenting forms is more fragile than frames, which were *designed* for being child controls, so prefer the frame technique.

The flicker on the taskbar comes from one form disappearing and another appearing. With either technique above, there's always just one form, never two, so there's nothing to flicker.

Comment: In addition you could also create two different processes and exchange data between them. That is of course a bit more expensive and may not be ideal if you have to share data.

Comment: That would be the opposite of preventing taskbar flicker, @Jens. The taskbar groups buttons from the same process, which is why Chau's code appears to replace one button with another — they occupy the same spot on the taskbar. But if the buttons belong to two different processes, then the taskbar will not keep them together. You'll have not only flickering buttons, but buttons that jump from one place to another.

Comment: Depends if they should be visible at the same time and if they are seperate enough for two different executables. The question is why Chau needs to change the main form anyway? I was speculating that it may be a better idea to either use two processes of the same executable or even two different ones.

Comment: My application has 3-4 forms.  User may jump from one form to another by pressing hot key or other means.  However, only one form is visible to user at any time.  Close any of the form will terminate the application.  That is the reason why I want to switch the main form at runtime.  I feel main form switching approach makes the design and coding simple.

Comment: Then use one of my suggestions above, @Chau. Use several *views* of a single form. Only one will be visible at a time, but since there's still just one top-level form, the OS doesn't get confused about what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

Another option to consider is to set `MainFormOnTaskbar=False`, then create a hidden MainForm for the lifetime of the process, and have `Form1` and `Form2` be secondary forms that you create and free dynamically when needed, and give them their own taskbar buttons by overriding the `TForms.CreateParams()` method, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;
end;
```

Comment: See The Old New Thing for why [it's wrong to make the desktop the parent of your application's windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx).